# Concurrent video frame processing using JavaCV

Tags: java, multithreading, javacv

I have a code that filter a video frame by frame using JavaCV. The code is like below

```
try (FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = createGrabber()) {
    grabber.start();
    try (FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = createRecorder(grabber)) {
        recorder.start();
        Frame frame;
        while ((frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
            Frame editedFrame = filterFrame(frame); //This takes a long time.
            recorder.setTimestamp(grabber.getTimestamp());
            recorder.record(editedFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the line `Frame editedFrame = filterFrame(frame);` takes quite a long time, is it possible to utilize multithreading so the whole process can be much faster? I was thinking using something like `ExecutorService` or `LinkedBlockingQueue` to process several frames in one time and then record the frame back according to the timestamp.

Comment: Can your filterFrame method (which you've not shown) utilise multi threading so it performs faster ?

Comment: yes, you can. but you should think about synchronize frames. probably you can split work in filterFrame like here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html. it would be more wise

Comment: @VladislavKysliy is it possible to have like executor service for like 4 threads, and then the filtering will be done every 4 frames and the frames will be recorded in the same sequence they're grabbed?

Comment: yes you can, but it could be tricky. just a moment try to write example

Comment: @PetraBarus is it helpful for you? any comments?

Comment: @VladislavKysliy somewhat still not working. I'm still trying to debug this.

Comment: If you can share a bit more code or some errors it will be very helpful

Comment: It seems that the frame grabber maintains state inside the frame. So far, in my understanding, whenever the `grab()` called, all the resources inside the current frame is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

It's [pattern producer](https://dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer):

Producer class is for executing long task(filterFrame):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class Producer implements Callable<Frame> {

    private final Frame frame;

    public Producer(Frame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public Frame call() throws Exception {
        return filterFrame(frame);
    }
}
```

Consumer class is for store frames:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Map.Entry<Long, Future<Frame>>> queue;
    public Boolean continueProducing = Boolean.TRUE;
    private final FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;

    public Consumer(FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder,
                    BlockingQueue<Map.Entry<Long, Future<Frame>>> queue) {
        this.recorder = recorder;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Map.Entry<Long, Future<Frame>> entry = this.queue.poll(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Frame editedFrame = entry.getValue().get();
            recorder.setTimestamp(entry.getKey());
            recorder.record(editedFrame);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the main part which manage tasks and shutdown threadPool

```
try (FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = createGrabber()) {
            grabber.start();
            try (FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = createRecorder(grabber)) {
                recorder.start();
                Frame frame;
                ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
                BlockingQueue<Map.Entry<Long, Future<Frame>>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
                threadPool.execute(new Consumer(recorder, queue));
                while ((frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
                    queue.put(new Map.Entry<Long, Future<Frame>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Long getKey() {
                            return grabber.getTimestamp();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Future<Frame> getValue() {
                            return threadPool.submit(new Producer(frame)); // Frame editedFrame = filterFrame(frame); //This takes a long time.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Future<Frame> setValue(Future<Frame> value) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                }
                threadPool.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
```

**Note:** It's no copy-paste solution and need some customization for your code. If you share more information i'll change it